# Bisubmodule Generated by a non-empty Subset

Tags: modules, bimodules

In module theory, let $A$ is a $C-$module and $Y$ is a non-empty subset of $A$. It is easy to prove that $B=\{ \sum_{y\in Y} cd | c\in C \}$ is the $C-$submodule of $A$ generated by $Y$.

Now, let $M$ is a $(R,S)-$bimodule and $X$ is any non-empty subset of $M$ and we define $N=\{ \sum_{x\in X} rxs | r\in R, s\in S \}$. Is $N$ a $(R,S)-$bisubmodule of $M$?

To prove $N$ is bisubmodule hence I need to show that:

1. $N$ is left $R-$submodule of M
2. $N$ is right $S-$submodule of M
3. for any $r\in R, s\in S$ and $n\in N$ we have $r(ms)=(rm)s$ which is obvious since we have $n\in M$ for every $n\in N$

Now, this is what I've tried to solve number 1:

Let $n_1,n_2\in N$ and $r_1,r_2\in R$, we need to show  $r_1n_1+r_2n_2\in N$. Since $n_1,n_2\in N$, we have $n_1=\sum_{x\in X} r'xs'$ for $r'\in R$ and $s'\in S$ and similarly $n_2=\sum_{x\in X} r''xs''$ for $r''\in R$ and $s''\in S$.

Then

> $r_1n_1+r_2n_2=r_1\sum_{x\in X} r'xs'+r_2\sum_{x\in X} r''xs''=\sum_{x\in X} r_1r'xs'+\sum_{x\in X} r_2r''xs''$
>   $r_1n_1+r_2n_2=\sum_{x\in X}(r_1r'xs'+r_2r''xs'')$

Here I got stuck since I can't group them by $s'$ and $s''$ because the term in $r_1r'xs'$ and $r_2r''xs''$ would be different. I need to group them to produce $r_1n_1+r_2n_2=\sum_{x\in X} r'''xs'''$ so that $r_1n_1+r_2n_2$ would be in $N$.

(if it is done then number 2 would also be done since they are similar).

Or is there any counter-example that $N$ is not-necessary to be a $(R,S)-$bisubmodule? If it is true then I need the counter-example.

Here, I only want to derive the concept of "generated submodule by a non-empty subset" to "generated bisubmodule by a non-empty subset".

There is also the possibility that the set $N=\{ \sum_{x\in X} rxs | r\in R, s\in S \}$ in the context of bimodule theory shouldn't be used to substitute the set $B=\{ \sum_{y\in Y} cd | c\in C \}$ in the context of module theory. Since I try to defined $N$ myself hence it may highly incorrect.

Therefore I need the correct definition of "$(R,S)-$bisubmodule of $M$ generated by a non-empty subset $X$ of $M$" because I can't find reference on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to allow finite multiplicity to get a bisubmodule by your definition.

It means you may have $r_1xs_1+r_2xs_2$ as an element of your bisubmodule without any force to represent it in singlton $r'xs'$ form.

Comment: what do you mean the multiciplity of $x$ by $r$ and $s$? If it is, yes I forgot to mention that the number of non-zero element of $r$ and $s$ in the combination linear of $\sum_{x\in X}rxs$ is finite. But I need the proof if it is a bisubmodule.

Comment: I add some clarification, hope address you. The finiteness of number of non-zero coefficient is always assumed, but explicitly be ignored. In my version also they remain finite, since $Finite \times Finite = Finite$

Comment: Ah I see, so I can write $N$ as follow: $N=\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i x s_i | n\in \mathbb{N}, x\in X, r_i\in R, s_i\in S\}$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I mean.

Comment: Lastly, for clarity I have written an answer below based on your suggestion. Please check it if it is correct. I will accept your answer after it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Let $n_1, n_2 \in N$ such that $$n_1=\underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}r_ixs_i$$ and   $$n_2=\underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}}r_ixs_i$$ 

Then for any $a,b \in R$ we have 

$$an_1+bn_2 = a\underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}r_ixs_i + b\underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}}r_ixs_i = \underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}\underbrace{(ar_i)}_{\in R}xs_i + \underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}}\underbrace{(br_i)}_{\in R}xs_i$$

$$an_1+bn_2 = \underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}}r'_ixs_i + \underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}}r'_ixs_i = \underset{x\in X}{\sum_{i=1}^{m}}r'_ixs_i \in N$$

Comment: Yes, it's correct. In the same way you can compute $n_1c+n_2d$, where $c,d \in S$.